# Why is Somnath of higher value than other Shiva lingas?

Tags: shiva

There is one sloka:

> Saurashtre Somanatham cha Srisaile Mallikarjunam|
>   Shankaram|
>   Setu Bandhe tu Ramesam, Nagesam Darukavane|
>   Varanasyantu Vishwesam, Tryambakam Gautamee thate|
>   Himalaye tu Kedaaram, Ghrishnesam cha shivaalaye|
>   Etani jyotirlingani, Saayam Praatah Patennarah|
>   Sapta Janma Kritam pApam, Smaranena Vinashyati Ujjayinya Mahakalam Omkaram amaleswaram|
>   Paralyam Vaidyanatham cha, Dakinyam Bheema

Now the question is, on what basis was the order decided? And I also heard that Somnath Mahadev has higher values then other Shiva lingas. Is that true?

Comment: Please correct my formatting if I messed anything up. Also, can you clarify what you mean by Somnath having "higher values"?

Comment: After reading this sloka, I don't see where it's mentioned that Somnath is of higher importance and all other jyotirlingas.

Comment: @VineetMenon as per the order it is.. and everybody does saying that.... Somnath Mahadeva is having heigher values then other shivlinga

Comment: I think the apparent higher importance is only because Somnath more than being a religious site is a historical site which has been rebuilt from it's ashes. religiously, I think each of the 4 Jyotirlinga is equal in importance.

Comment: @VineetMenon do u have any more information .. so please share it here

Answer (score 9):

It is not that Somnath Mahadev has higher values then other Shiva lingas. Somnath Mahadev is the first *Jyotirling* among the 12 Jyotirlings. All the 12 jyotirlings have different importance and symbolism, you can't compare any of the Jyotirlings as its said *Lord Shiva* himself is present there and *Lord Shiva* is the same. Its just that *Somnath Mahadev* is taken first in shlok. To know more about Jyotirlings, refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyotirlinga).

Answer (score 6):

No it is nothing about order or nothing like higher value. <kbd>SID M</kbd> is absolutely right that it is taken first in shloka.

### Importance of Somnath Jyotirlinga

*Somanatha Jyotirlinga* which is shiva's manifestation for protection of moon, when Chandra dev was cursed.

On the prayer of mother of "Asuras" demons -> **Asurmata** , Lord Shiva blessed her that if any of her sons , with pure heart, prays to Shiva with *Somanatha Jyotirlinga* , will be illegible for heaven directly!!

So Many demons entered in heaven and Indra did not like that. So he went to Vishnu who denied that he can not do anything against Shiva's will. Indra then went to mother of devas(deities) and asked her to pray to Parvati(Shakti).

Parvati promised her that she will help Indra and she sent Ganesha to stop Asuras from entering heaven. Then Lord Shiva and Parvati appeared and Shiva asked Ganesha to stop. Shiva told that Somnatha is just a way to heaven for those who are asura mata's sons. Meanwhile Rishi Kashyap asks his wife asuramata about the causes in heavan due to asuras. She asks mahadev to take his blessings back, but shiva says, any body who is wishing to go to heavan, if with pure heart prays to Somnatha Jyotirlinga, his wish will be fulfilled.

And thus it has the importance that Somnath Mahaev's prayer from pure heart may bring you heaven!!

**Reference** - Shiva Maha Puran

Comment: Parth, Please use italics for emphasis and not the code style. Code blocks are for entirely different purpose.

Comment: I changed them to italics... but please tell me when to use code style?

Comment: thank you.. Code style is used mainly for pre-formatted texts such as codes. I don't know who can this context be applied to Hi.SE.